# How to Upload Files and Data as form data with python using request library to asp.net api

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, python-requests, .net-6.0

I'm trying to upload a file with data using python requests library. Both the data parameters and file should be recieved as Form data into a model in .Net but its throwing a 400 error. Can't figure out what I need to change to get api to correctly recieve the data. It's hitting the backend controller but not properly being recieved by API.

Python Code

```
 filename = fileList[getListElementInRange(fileList, i)]
            f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            print(f)
            with open(f, 'rb') as file:
                formData = {
                    'File': file,
                    'UserId': user_id,
                    'Name': "test file"
                }
                headers = {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                }

                r = requests.post("http://localhost:5000/api/image/uploadFile",
                                  data=formData, headers=headers)
                print("Response code img:", r.status_code)
                print("Response content img:", r.content)
```

C# API

```
 [HttpPost("uploadFile")]
        public async Task UploadFileWithModel([FromForm] ImageWithDetailsModel imageModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var UserId = imageModel.UserId;
                var userImageFolder = "";
                var thumb = "Thumb";
                if (imageModel.File != null)
                {



                    userImageFolder = Path.Combine(TempImageFolder, UserId);
                    var userThumbNailFolder = Path.Combine(TempImageFolder, UserId, "Thumb", imageModel.File.FileName);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(userImageFolder);

                    var fileFullPath = Path.Combine(TempImageFolder, UserId, imageModel.File.FileName);

                    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(fileFullPath))
                    {
                        await imageModel.File.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }

                    var UserIdTest = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
                    // add to db
                    Photo photoDetails = new Photo
                    {
                        PathName = fileFullPath,
                        PhotoName = imageModel.File.FileName,
                        UserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User)
                    };

                    _dbContext.Photos.Add(photoDetails);
                    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                    

                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }


        }
```

Image With Detail Model

```
    public class ImageWithDetailsModel
    {
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }

        public String? UserId { get; set; }

        public String? Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Logged out error messages

```
Response code img: 400
Response content img: b'{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-6c762e3b5709f8fafa936793ecc624ff-ac52c6b5c66bb2dd-00","errors":{"":["Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."]}}'
```